How do I get my ForEach to wait until my query completes before incrementing
I have a forEach loop that has a query being run inside of it. How do I get it to wait for the query to complete before it moves to the next index?
Here is some sample code of what I am trying to do:
quest=[{questid:1,question:"How are you?",sort:3,type:1},{questid:2,question:"How is the weather?",sort:1,type:2},...]
temp=[]
quest.forEach((question)=>{
   if(question.type==1){
      question.answer=[];
      temp.push(question)
   } else{

       connection.query(`SELECT choice_id,choice_descr FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE questionid = ${question.questionid},
          (err, results, fields) => {
            question.answer=results
            temp.push(question)
          }
   }
})

I basically want to push these into the temp array in the same order that currently are in the quest array but it keeps pushing the objects that satisfy the conditions of my first if and then pushing the others.
Any idea how to fix this?

It seems you can execute all queries in parallel.
Use async/await and Promise.all/Promise.withResolvers:

temp = await Promise.all(quest.map((question)=>{
   if(question.type==1){
      question.answer=[];
      return question;
   } else{
      const {promise, resolve, reject} = Promise.withResolvers();
       connection.query(`SELECT choice_id,choice_descr FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE questionid = ${question.questionid}`,
          (err, results, fields) => {
            if(err) return reject(err);
            question.answer=results
            resolve(question);
          }
      return promise;
   }
});


You can also use Promise.all(...).then(questions => ...).
Make sure to properly use await either inside an async function/IIFE or in the top level of a module.

The question clearly states that parallel operations are not the objective.

It's a great solution for a forum where users help single users with individual problems, but this is a question and answer platform with the goal to help future users with similar questions and this answer doesn't answer the question: "How do I get my ForEach to wait until my query completes before incrementing" You could post this as a comment as an alternative approach.
